# filter cost center with GL account and take the total

Tags: filter

I am trying to filter the column "E" with each cost center, column "L" with each GL account and get the sum of amount column "I" in new sheet with entire row values. Also the negative amount to be highlighted. There are 75000 rows with 200 cost centers.

[image]

Comment: Please suggest on the above doubt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.